# How to detect with expl3 if the code is currently in the preamble?

Tags: expl3, preamble

I would like to know the standard way using expl3 to test whether a command is running within the preamble or inside the main body. My current approach is to use:

```
\cs_if_eq:NNTF \@onlypreamble \@notprerr
  { code if not in the preamble }
  { code if in the preamble }
```

More precisely, when there is a part of the command that requires to be inside the main body (for example, when it tries to modify some macros that are delayed to `\AtEndPreamble`), I tends to use the following `\__atbegindocument_if_needed:n` to place an `\AtBeginDocument` if the command is running in preamble:

```
\cs_new:Nn \__nochange:n {#1}
\cs_new:Nn \__atbegindocument:n {#1}
\cs_new:Nn \__atbegindocument_if_needed:n
  {
    \cs_if_eq:NNTF \@onlypreamble \@notprerr
      {
        \cs_gset_eq:NN \__atbegindocument:n \__nochange:n
      }
      {
        \cs_gset_eq:NN \__atbegindocument:n \AtBeginDocument
      }
    \__atbegindocument:n {#1}
  }
```

Though it works, this method seems to be quite inelegant.

Comment: expl3 is not about document preamble and similar. So you need a LaTeX2e way.

Comment: There is no abstraction for LaTeX commands in expl3. Also you're using this the wrong way around. You should define your commands and then say `\@onlypreamble \my_cool_cmd:Nnw` or so.

Comment: The standard way is to give the command the preamble definition, then `\AtBeginDocument` redefine your command to the document body version

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you for this hint! I didn't think of this and I usually begin my command with the detection. The standard way is simpler and better.

Comment: @Jinwen "standard" as in "what people usually do"; it's not a law or anything like that.  It has the benefit that you don't need any runtime checks (so it's faster), and LaTeX takes care of the timing for you

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I just added to the question with my usual approach, one that is being adopted in the current version of the package `crefthe`. May I ask your opinion of possible improvements or alternative methods?

Comment: @Jinwen If I understand your code, if it's used in the preamble it does `\AtBeginDocument`, otherwise it just executes the code.  If that's the case, then just use `\AddToHook{begindocument}{<code>}`.  `begindocument` is a so-called "one-time hook", which means that after it's executed, any attempt to add code to it will just execute that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understood correctly what the question is about—let me recap. In case I didn't understand correctly please clarify in a comment:

A command that processes an argument shall behave differently depending on whether it is carried out within the preamble or within the document environment:

In the preamble, it should execute `\AtBeginDocument{<argument>}`.

In the document environment it should simply deliver its argument.

As gusbrs pointed out in his [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632460/how-to-detect-with-expl3-if-the-code-is-currently-in-the-preamble/632472?noredirect=1#comment1577180_632472), with up-to-date TeX-distributions where the new hook-system is available you can just add things to the one-time-hook `begindocument` or—if the material to be added to the hook is to be typeset or to be carried out when already in the document—to the hook `begindocument/end`:

Just do `\AddToHook{begindocument}{<Tokens to add>}` or `\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{<Tokens to add>}`.

If the one-time-hook was already executed, `<Tokens to add>` will be processed immediately.

(Information on LaTeX's new hook-system can be found in
["LaTeX's hook management" by Frank Mittelbach](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/lthooks-code.pdf) and in [source2e.pdf, section "File h: lthooks.dtx"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf#part.8) and in  [source2e.pdf, section "file i: ltcmdhooks.dtx"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf#part.9) and in [source2e.pdf, section "file T: ltfilehook.dtx"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf#part.46).)

In case you are working with a less recent TeX-distribution where the new hook-system is not available:

Testing whether `\@onlypreamble` is equivalent to `\@notprerr` seems fine to me.
However, I don't know how things work out with document classes/packages like [standalone](https://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) or [combine](https://ctan.org/pkg/combine).

If you don't mind repeating the `\ifx`-test for equality of  `\@onlypreamble`  and `\@notprerr` with each call to the command—`\cs_if_eq:NNTF` is an expl3 wrapper for the `\ifx`-test, you could wrap that test in `\use:c`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__atbegindocument_if_needed:n {
  \use:c {
     \cs_if_eq:ccTF {@onlypreamble} {@notprerr} {use:n} {AtBeginDocument}
  }
}

\__atbegindocument_if_needed:n {This~should~be~added~to~the~AtBeginDocument-hook.}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\__atbegindocument_if_needed:n {This~should~be~carried~out~immediately.}
\ExplSyntaxOff
  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm also not sure that's what the OP is intending. But, since `begindocument` is a "one time hook", any code you try to add to it after it has run is executed immediately. So, as far as I understand, this workaround is not necessary: just use `\AddToHook{begindocument}{do your stuff}`.

Comment: Well, what to say?... true. Still not a very commendable procedure.  ;-)

Comment: And, as far as I can tell, the difference between `begindocument` and `begindocument/end` is not particularly significant for the use case at hand. Feel free to add to your answer, I don't intend to add one of my own, since I'm not sure this is what the OP wants.

Comment: The correct hook to use will depend on what OP wants to do.  Usually, `begindocument` is the right choice, because it's the official "the document starts here", but for example, `\@onlypreamble` commands can still be used there (you can load packages in `begindocument`), whereas `begindocument/end` is equivalent to typing the code after `\begin{document}`.  Usually, you should use `begindocument`, and leave `begindocument/end` for special cases

Answer (score 3):

This is the definition of `\@onlypreamble`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 1168:
\def\@onlypreamble#1{%
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\@preamblecmds\expandafter{%
       \@preamblecmds\do#1}}
```

Up to `\begin{document}` the macro `\@preamblecmds` will contain a list of items of the form

```
\do<command>
```

starting with `\do\@onlypreamble\do\@preamblecmds`.

When processing `\begin{document}`, LaTeX does

```
  \gdef\do##1{\global\let ##1\@notprerr}%
  \@preamblecmds
```

so the commands in the list are all `\let` to `\@notprerr`.

It's not really clear what you want to achieve. But it's not generally the best user interface having the same command doing very different things in the preamble and in the document.

If you want to do this, your package/class can do

```
\newcommand\foo{whatever you want in the preamble}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand\foo{whatever you want in the document}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. In some of my commands, there is a small part that requires to be inside the main body (for example modifies the value of macros that already `\AtBeginDocument`) and I usually use such a detection to decide whether a `\AtBeginDocument` is necessary. With the method you mentioned in the last, do I have to repeat the shared code for the preamble and the document twice? (The commands usually have a few optional arguments that can be left empty or not given, it seems hard to define a core function first and then call it inside the main function)

Comment: @Jinwen look at LaTeX's new hooks system and see whether those could fix your decision whether an `\AtBeginDocument` is necessary. E.g., if you only need to patch things if a certain package is loaded, you could do `\AddToHook{package/<name>/after}{<code>}` to inject `<code>` after the package`<name>` was loaded. And with the sorting rules you could also manage hooks in `\AtBeginDocument`.

Comment: @Skillmon Thank you for the suggestion! This is new knowledge to me, could you please give me an idea where can I learn about the hooks system?

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/632463),

```tex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \g_mylib_preamble_bool
\bool_gset_true:N \g_mylib_preamble_bool

% the same as \AtBeginDocument{ \bool_gset_... }
\hook_gput_code:nnn {begindocument} {top-level} 
  { \bool_gset_false:N \g_mylib_preamble_bool }

% in your code
\bool_if:NTF \g_mylib_preamble_bool
  {<true code>}{<false code>}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Note detecting `\g_mylib_preamble_bool`'s value inside `\begin{document}`, especially in the hook `begindocument` is still inaccurate.

Comment: `\g_preamble_bool`  is not a good name. There should be a module prefix.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. Added a poor module name `mylib`.